# useEffect order and defining when to run

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I have my main function to check authorization in `App.js` as such:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      // @ts-ignore
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        dispatch(logoutUser());
      } else {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
        dispatch(getUser());
      }
    }
  }, [token, dispatch]);
```

I then have useEffects in the components and there are times when some `useEffect()` get executed first and therefore some `dispatch` get executed before authorization is retrieved.

How can I ensure my `App.js — useEffect()` get's executed before anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do so, involving `Lazy` import etc.. but the most straight forward way is to create loading state that accords rest app gonna render

---

```
const [ initLoading, setInitLoading ] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
if (token) {
  let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  // @ts-ignore
  if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
    dispatch(logoutUser());
  } else {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    dispatch(getUser());
  }
 setInitLoading(false)
}
}, [token, dispatch]);

return(
  <>
   { initLoading ? <div> loading </div> : <YourApp /> }
  </>
 )
```